# Choose a sub series of a random series, such that its expectation can be a given real number

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probabilistic-number-theory

Suppose $a>0$, and we have an infinite series of Bernoulli random variables $B_k$ with
$$\mathbb{Pr}{\large[}B_k=1{\large]} = \frac{1}{1+e^{a\cdot 2^k}}$$

Then
$$\text{E}\left[\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}{2^k}{B_k}\right] = \frac{1}{a}$$
and in fact the sum inside the brackets follows the exponential distribution with parameter $a$.

**Question:** Given $b>a$, can we find a subset $I \subset \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$\text{E}\left[\sum_{k \in I}{2^k}{B_k}\right]=\frac{1}{b}\ ?$$

Comment: I can't verify your $1/a$ claim. For $a=2$, even the sum of the first two terms exceeds $1/2$. Also the sum is evidently less than 1 for any $a>0$ so it can't equal $1/a$ when $0<a<1$.

Comment: I mess up with the transformation. The problem you mentioned is fixed now.

Comment: How do you prove $$\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty \frac{2^j}{1+\exp(a 2^j)}=\frac1a\ ?$$ It works when I replace the sum with an integral, because then the indefinite integral is $-\log(1+\exp(-a 2^j))/(a \log 2)$, and I can verify the sum numerically, but neither I nor Mathematica can readily prove that sum formula.

Comment: We can use the characteristic function of $B_k$: $E[e^{itB_k}] = \frac{1+e^{(it-a)\cdot 2^k}}{1+e^{-a\cdot 2^k}} $, and the equation $\prod_{k=0}^n(1+e^{a\cdot 2^k})=\frac{1-e^{a\cdot2^{k+1}}}{1-e^a}$. Then the characteristic fucntion of the product term turns to be equal to $\frac{a}{a-it}$, which is just the characteristic function of exponential distribution with parameter $a$.

More details can be found in the paper:

Marsaglia, George. "Random variables with independent binary digits." The Annals of Mathematical Statistics (1971): 1922-1929.

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4503817) from MSE.